# SQL - Divide by AS Result

Tags: sql, divide

I'm an SQL novice just trying to figure this one out.

```
,(
    ISNULL([era_project_data_analysis].annual_spend_after_implementation,
        ISNULL([era_project_data_analysis].annual_spend_after_selection,
            ISNULL([era_project_data_analysis].annual_spend_after_recommendations,
                [era_project_data_analysis].estimated_annual_spend              
            )
        )
    )       
) AS [Annual Spend],
```

I want to divide by the result of this sub-select like this:

[Table].[annual_savings] / [Annual Spend] AS 'Savings %'

But 'Annual Spend' in as Invalid column name? :(

Comment: use CTE. Otherwise, you have to repeat your expression.

Answer (score 0):

Unless that definition of [Annual Spend] is in a sub query (either as a sub-query or as a CTE if the DB supports it), you can not reference the field by name, but would have to use the same code again.

I would also use Coalesce over nested isnull's like that unless you expected some of the edge cases between isnull and coalesce for your specific DB - which are relatively rare, 
`COALESCE(era_project_data_analysis].annual_spend_after_implementation, [era_project_data_analysis].annual_spend_after_selection, [era_project_data_analysis].annual_spend_after_recommendations, [era_project_data_analysis].estimated_annual_spend )`

I would also use Table alias's to avoid the code above looking so bad.